# Calculating complexity when two recursive calls are involved

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

How to calculate complexity when there are more than one recursive calls?

Such as in this problem.

```
F(n)
{
   if (n is 1)
     return;
   F(n/2)  //Call 1
   F(n/3)  //Call 2
   F(n/6)  //Call 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to solve the equation,

`T(n)=T(n/2)+T(n/3)+T(n/6)+O(1)`

Now as T(n/2)>T(n/3), we can instead solve for

`T(n)=3T(n/2)+O(1)`

Using [master's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), T(n)=O(n^(log(base 2)3))=O(n^1.58)

Note that there might be better solution but as this is Big O notation, this is valid too

Comment: Would be great if you post the proof :)

Comment: OK I was wrong, but only slightly. I have written up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

I believe I can prove that the complexity of this function is O(n<sup>c</sup>) for any c > 1.

Recall the definition of big-O notation. We say a function g(n) is O(f(n)) if there exist constants k and n' such that g(n) < k*f(n) for all n > n'. (Colloquially, g(n) is bounded above by f(n) for sufficiently large n, ignoring constant factors.)

Pick any c > 1, and observe that for sufficiently large n,

1 > (1/2)<sup>c</sup> + (1/3)<sup>c</sup> + (1/6)<sup>c</sup> + 1/n<sup>c</sup>

This is easy to see because 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 = 1, and (1/2)<sup>c</sup> < 1/2 etc. because c > 1. And when n is big enough, 1/n<sup>c</sup> is arbitrarily small.

Multiply through by n<sup>c</sup>, to get that for sufficiently large n:

n<sup>c</sup> > (n/2)<sup>c</sup> + (n/3)<sup>c</sup> + (n/6)<sup>c</sup> + 1

Therefore, if the running time of F(m) is bounded above by m<sup>c</sup> for m=n/2, m=n/3, and m=n/6, then the running time of F(n) is bounded above by n<sup>c</sup>. Result follows by induction.

So although I was wrong that this function is O(n), it is arbitrarily close... In the sense that for any positive value epsilon, no matter how small, the function is O(n<sup>1+epsilon</sup>).

...

In general, for this type of question, I think you want to guess solutions of the form n<sup>c</sup> and then try to place a bound on c. This is essentially how the Master Theorem itself works.